# Pytables time performance

Tags: performance, pytables

I'm working on a project related to text detection in natural images. I have to train a classifier and for that i'm using Pytables to store information. I have:

- 62 classes (a-z,A-Z,0-9)
- Each class has between 100 and 600 tables
- Each table has 1 single column to store a 32bit Float
- Each column has between 2^2 and 2^8 rows (depending on parameters)

  My problem is that after I train the classifier, it takes a lot of time to read the information in the test. For example: One database has 27900 tables (62 classes * 450 tables per class) and there are 4 rows per table , it took aprox 4hs to read and retrieve all the information I need. The test program read each table 390 times (for classes A-Z, a-z) and 150 times for classes 0-9  to get all the info I need. Is that normal?
  I tried to use the index option for the  unique column , but I dont see any performance. I work on a VirtualMachine with 2GB Ram on a HP Pavillion Dv6 (4GB Ram DDR3, Core2 Duo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because column lookup on tables is one of the slower operations you can do and this is where ALL of your information lives.  You have two basic options to increase performance for Tables with many columns and few rows:

1. Pivot this structure such that you have a Table with many rows and few columns.
2. Move to a more efficient data structure like a CArray or EArray for every row / column.

Additionally, you can try using compression to speed things up.  This is sort of generic advice, because you haven't included any code.